# mapping function to map the index of Lower triangular matrix

Tags: data-structures, arrays, matrices

If I have a Lower triangular matrix of order n and I want to store non-null elements of this matrix in 1D array from first row to last row and within a row from left to right. What could be the mapping function to map the index of Lower triangular matrix Aij in 1D.

Comment: As you want a compact representation of a sparsely populated matrix, it will not be trivial. Triangular may prove not much help. What operations need to be supported/fast?

Comment: (There is [help on What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers))

Comment: In the opposite direction, given the 1D index, compute the row : Convert lower-left matrix triangle 1D index to row, column : https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/155949/ .

Answer (score 1):

Index of $A_{i,j}$ in $1$-$D$ will be $\frac{i(i-1)}{2} + j$ assuming $1$ based indexing.

Comment: This maps *all* elements while the question reads *store non-null elements*.

Comment: @greybeard I assumed that non-null elements are those that are in upper triangular region of the matrix. I think it is not clear what OP means by non null elements.